# Need to get rid of part-m-0000* files in HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop

In HDFS processing after each job empty files are created with names like part-m-0000*. Each of these files are empty but they are consuming 64MB of disk space because that is default size of block.

It is necessary to make code changes to skip creation of these files. How do I do this?

Note: I am using `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs<KEYOUT,VALUEOUT>` to write output records, and not Context, so I anyways end up with output records in files like "successful-m-00000" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Hadoop : The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010388.do), so the underlying file system will not take a HDFS block size if the file is empty.

> Unlike a filesystem for a single disk, a file in HDFS that is smaller than a single block does not occupy a full block’s worth of underlying storage.

For suppressing the output files if they are empty, use [LazyOutputFormat#setOutputFormatClass](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/LazyOutputFormat.html#setOutputFormatClass%28org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf,%20java.lang.Class%29). Here is the Apache [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html#Lazy+Output+Creation) for the same.